# Lombok @Builder not working for a custom implementation of a field in Entity class

Tags: lombok

I want to capitalize the value when it is set to a String type field. I am using lombok @Builder with a custom builder to do this. However, not getting desired result ! Code is below-

```
@Table(value = “user_table”)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserEntity {

    @JsonProperty(“name") private String name;
    @JsonProperty(“age”) private Integer age;

    public static class UserEntityBuilder {
      public UserEntityBuilder name(String name) {
        this.name = StringUtils.upperCase(name);
        return this;
      }
    }
}
```

So, if I get JSON as {"name":"abc", "age":22}, this should be persisted in the user_table as below, the value in 'name' is in uppercase -

### | name | age |

ABC     22

but the values is save as

### | name | age |

abc     22

|Solution 1|

```
@Table(value = “user_table”)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {    
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty(“age”) private Integer age;
    @JsonSetter("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = StringUtils.upperCase(name);
    }
}
```

|Solution 2|

```
@Table(value = “user_table”)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {
    @JsonProperty(“name”) 
    @JsonDeserialize(using = NameDeserializer.class)
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty(“age”) private Integer age;

    public static class NameDeserializer 
             extends StdDeserializer<String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public NameDeserializer() { this(null); }
        public NameDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { super(vc);   }

        @Override
        public String deserialize(
               JsonParser p, 
               DeserializationContext ctxt
             ) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            return StringUtils.upperCase(p.getText());
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get instead, can you share ?

Comment: based on @jan-rieke answer, 2 solns possible for my use case... 1. @JsonSetter method for `name` field and 2. custom deserializer for `name` field... yes point 2 being 'too much' work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming from the usage of `@JsonProperty` that you are deserializing using Jackson. There is no magic auto-detection of builders in Jackson. You have to explicitly tell Jackson that it should use a specific builder class to construct instances.

In your example, Jackson simply creates an instance of `UserEntity` with the generated `@NoArgsConstructor`. Then it sets the field values via reflection (it does not need setters to do so). So your code in the builder is never used.

If you want Jackson to deserialize using the builder, you have to add this before `UserEntity`:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(builder = UserEntity.UserEntityBuilder.class)
```

Furthermore, you have to tell Jackson how the setter methods in the builder are named:

```java
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class UserEntityBuilder {
        ...
    }
```

However, let me note that this approach seems a bit "too much" for your use case. Why don't you just add setter methods to `UserEntity` itself and do the upper-casing in those?